# How to view dynamic data in same page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey guys suppose i have 20 buttons in a same page and every button directs user to its relative page with few links, so should i create 20 other pages for each of this text buttons or there's way to show these respective links in same page ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open a hyperlink, I would suggest to create a new page with webview and pass different links via navigator on different button click to open the different webpages.

Comment: actually i want to display different pdfs on click of different buttons... can i do that.. and also i only want that pdfs to be shown in the same app not in browser or something

Comment: use https://pub.dev/packages/pdf this plugin and create a page and pass different URLs or path for rendering on different button clicks.